# How to get the object in constructor in MEF Framework same as AspNet Core Identity UserManager implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, mef

I am using ASPNET.Core.Identity UserManager as constructor parameter in my class

```
public class UserService
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {

        }
    }
```

When I resolve the MEF container using

```
UserService= container.GetExportedValue<UserService>();
```

I am getting a error as "'No exports were found that match the constraint'"

My question is how to get the usermanager object without initializing usermanager object.

As I saw in many examples regarding ASPNET.Core.Identity UserManager, The UserManger object is configured in Startup class and using dependency injection we can get the object in constructor how to do the same in MEF?